# Scraping commented out tables in R

Tags: r, xml, web-scraping

This identical bit of code I'm using worked like a charm a month or two ago. Now, upon revisiting the project, I've found that it no longer works at all. My knowledge on this subject matter is hazy to begin with; I derived this code from a question I had to ask on this very forum earlier. Can anyone explain what's going on, or what likely happened? The only thing I can think of is if the webpage I'm scraping changed their code in some way, maybe mine no longer reflects those changes? Here's what I'm working with (I apologize for all the packages referenced below. I don't know if any of them are used in this bit of code or not):

```
library(rvest)
library(XML)
library(tidyr)
library(zoo)
library(chron)
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
page.201702050atl = read_html("http://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201702050atl.htm")
comments.201702050atl = page.201702050atl %>% html_nodes(xpath = "//comment()")
game.info.201702050atl = comments.201702050atl[17] %>% html_text() %>% read_html() %>% html_node("#game_info") %>% html_table()
```

And here's the error message I'm getting:

```
> game.info.201702050atl = comments.201702050atl[17] %>% html_text() %>% read_html() %>% html_node("#game_info") %>% html_table()
Error: ' /div.#akunit_mobile_1 ' does not exist in current working directory ('C:/Users/Brandon/Documents/Data Prophets/Football').
```

Thanks for the helps!

Comment: I can't access any football websites, but they might have an error with the div id (or class) assignment.  Drop the commands off the pipe that is giving errors until you find the culprit.

Comment: You're extracting the text of a comment " /div.#akunit_mobile_1 ", passing that to `read_html` which interprets it as a file path, then hoping that an HTML table comes out the other end. It's no surprise that this doesn't work. Maybe start by explaining which table from the original web page you are hoping to extract?

Comment: Yes the page changed.  Try: `comments.201702050atl[14]`